# scrollbars="vertical" is not working in TextView

Tags: android, textview, scrollbar

Scrollbar is showing but not working or scrolling as shown in image below

[image: TextView with Scrollbar]

**XML:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_dialog_notes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:hint="@string/rv_notes_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:minLines="10"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:textSize="17sp" />
```

Where is something wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using scrollbar on textView**

you have to add this line in java

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure you add that to your code:

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```